# WIN32 API PostMessage synchronization

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, sendmessage

I am trying to remote control an application.
In particular I Try to send the function key F5 to notepad.exe.

notepad.exe on F5 usually reacts by pasting the actual time/date in it's edit area.

The code I have figure out so far:

```
/********************************************************************/

org = GetActiveWindow(); // get current active window

ShowWindow(w, SW_RESTORE); // do the switch to the notepad window

PostMessage(w, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F5, 0); // send/post F5

Sleep(100); // need this to wait for the notepad action to complete

ShowWindow(org, SW_SHOW); // restore org window

/********************************************************************/
```

So far the code works more or less.

The problem that remains is how long will I have wait using `Sleep()`, how many milliseconds will be sufficient?
Waiting to short will switch back to the original window before notepad.exe has completed the F5 task.

notepad.exe will loose focus and the F5 command will get lost because only an focused notepad will process it.

It would be much nicer to use `SendMessage()` as this waits for completion

```
/********************************************************************/

SendMessage(w, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F5, 0); // should sync on the completion of F5

/********************************************************************/
```

Unfortunately notepad.exe does not react on F5 when using SendMessage instead of PostMessage.

Is there a clean way to synchronize the desired task?

Note actually notepad.exe is just an example for a more complex remote control task.

Comment: Use UI Automation, the official automation API, to automate applications

Comment: Impossible to guess what GetActiveWindow() is supposed to accomplish, it only ever returns the active window of *your* app, never of another process.  Also very unclear how `w` and `org` are supposed to be related.  This cannot work as intended.  Focus on writing your own apps before you try to mess with other ones, only decent way to learn enough about the winapi.

Comment: Better use `SendInput`.

Comment: Hi Hans, w of course is a window handle to notepadd and org is a window handle to the window of the c++ programm I am writing.

Comment: Hi Werner, SendInput as I Understand only results in SendMessage WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP messages. notepad will not react on this. This would work for simple characters to be input in the edit area, not working for commands like F5 to be performed.

Comment: Use COM or named pipes for inter-application communication in Windows. It is lot simpler than to emulate user input through those keyboard and mouse messages and to read user output by "looking" at the contents of windows.

Comment: Hi Tiib, would this approach work e.g. wit notepad.exe? Could you give a further hint?

Comment: @Robert: `SendInput` places input events into the input event queue, the same way a driver does. This does not result in `SendMessage` invocations; input messages are posted to the receiving thread's message queue. Consequently, when `SendInput` returns, it does not imply that input has been handled.

Comment: @RobertNowak that still does not change the fact that `SendMessage()` is the wrong way to send input to a foreign window. You will have to use a UI automation method or `SendInput()`. (As for Öö Tiib's comment: Both the newer UI Automation (that David Hefferman told you about) and the older MSAA are COM-based.) Also wait, is `w` the handle to Notepad's window or to its child edit control? (I don't know how Notepad handles keyboard shortcuts...)

Comment: OK, have switched now to `SendInput()` this works a little bit nicer, but it actually performs like a kind of "`PostInput()`" not waiting for the action to be finished. So still need to insert `Sleep()` before switching away form the target window failing to do so a portion the remaining input feeds into the wrong window.

Comment: I don't like to say it but I can't resist: Why do you do this? Can't you just open a file and write date/time on your own. Change your method.

Comment: Hi Mustafa as I stated in my very first post: Note actually notepad.exe is just an example for a more complex remote control task. Date/Time is just an example for a much more complex task.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, an app can choose to respond to `WM_KEYUP` only on some keys (`WM_KEYDOWN` may be too early,) so you should try `SendMessage(w, WM_KEYUP...)` after `WM_KEYDOWN`.

Comment: [Please don't use `SendMessage()` to send input.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx) [(Part 2)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/28/10190521.aspx)